# What physical parameters are really being described when a rope manufacturer cites "elongation %"?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science

I have a precision pulley system sensitive to micron displacements. I am having issues because I need a cord with low tensioning force, but also low stretch.  I am getting some weird hysteresis in the system and I think it has to do with stretching of the cord.

There are some interesting materials out there such as spectra polyethylene, zylon (PPO), and vectra but I want to be able to make some calculations to know how much a given length of this cord will stretch under load, and also how much force it actually takes to tension it.

How am I supposed to work with this "elongation %" metric?  Shouldn't there be some sort of modulus or poisson ratio for the material?  I am not a mechanical engineer.

Could it be the % elongation that must occur before the rope becomes tensioned?  This is still lacking for making my calculations.

I am also wondering if the diameter of the cord is important for this. My intuition is yes, the thicker the diameter cord, the less % stretch will be experienced along the length when under load.

For one example see here:
http://www.twinline-usa.com/prod_specs.php

Comment: "Two kinds of stretch occur in cable based on wire rope: constructional stretch and elastic stretch. This stretch is due to two different causes."

Comment: "1. Constructional Stretch - When cable is made, the load at the closing head is light. Therefore, there are small clearances between the wires and strands, and between the strand and the core. The application of initial load causes wires and strands to seat properly and a slight overall elongation of the strand or cable accompanies this section. The amount of constructional stretch is not constant for all cables - it depends on such variables as type of construction, length of lay, and other factors, including the load applied."

Comment: "2. Elastic Stretch - Elastic stretch is the actual elongation of the wires of a strand or a cable. This is caused by the application of a load up to the yield point of the metal. The stretch is approximately proportional to the load applied. When the load is released, cable subjected to elastic stretch returns to its approximate original length, providing the stretch has not reached the yield point of the metal."

Comment: "When the elimination of as much stretch as possible is important, the cables or assemblies can be proof loaded to remove most of the constructional stretch. For assemblies, this process also verifies the holding power of the terminals. Proof loading is usually done by applying a 60% load to the cable or assemblies. This load is based on the minimum breaking strength of the cable or fittings, whichever is lower. Handling the cable as little as possible after prestretching helps eliminate putting constructional stretch back in."